# GLMM Random vs Fixed terms R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have proportion data that I would like to analyze using GLMM - I have some fixed and random terms to incorporate in the formula, but I do not understand how I structure the syntax. `Quad` and `YEAR` in `MyData` are my crossed Random Terms (Year of survey (3 in total) and quad where the survey was done (4 in total).

```
library(lme4)
# Response variable (No of positives and negatives)
y<-cbind(POSPLANTS,NEGPLANTS)
# Create dataframe with variables from MyData that will become fixed terms:
data <-data.frame(PREC,ALT,INFTYPE,VARIETY,POSPLANTS,NEGPLANTS)
model<-glmer(y~PREC+ALT+INFTYPE+VARIETY+ (1|YEAR) +(1|Quad),binomial,data=data)
summary(model)
```

Is it right? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: A couple of comments on your code (unrelated to your question). Don't attach data. Just use `data.frame`, not `data.frame(cbind(`, as if any of your variables are character, then it will coerce all variables to character (including the numerics), which will then be converted to factors by data.frame.

Comment: Re the random effects, you will need to explain what the variables are. And probably worth mentioning what is not *right* ; -errors? warnings? nonsense results?

Comment: `glmer` comes from `lme4`

Comment: You model quad and year as nested random effects. Are they nested or are they crossed? Also, fixed effects can't simultaneously be random effects.

Comment: thanks for the comments, i addressed them in the question. The random effects are crossed @Roland

Comment: Crossed random intercepts: `y ~ PREC + ALT + INFTYPE + VARIETY + (1 | YEAR) + (1 | Quad)`.